# Looking for a sci-fi comic about a female soldier of fortune

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a comic I've read as a German translation (maybe Carlsen?) in the 1990s. I think it was a French or Belgian comic in the first place.

The series follows a female agent/mercenary on earth and in space:
She frees a guy from a cryo-prison on a oil rig like platform in the sea. Whereupon they get hunted (maybe Australia?) and end up fleeing to the moon, which is aboriginal territory. On the moon there is a ruin where a giant holiday resort should have been built. In space she's wearing a red space suit (also on one of the covers) and that's about it what I can remember :(

The style of drawing was a bit like a manga (colored) and rather modern albeit with some rather curvy females.

The name was MacMillian/McMilan/something but my searches were fruitless. It was a longer story split/over multiple volumes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: What do you mean by "curvy and unnatural females ;)"? The winky face adds to the confusion.

Comment: I removed that part as this seems to be the "standard" in comics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [Carmen Mc Callum](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmen_Mc_Callum), published by Delcourt in 1995.

Here's the synopsis (Google Translate):

> In the near future (2053), detainees are cryogenized awaiting trial.
>   The mercenary Carmen Mc Callum makes escape Naoko Sonoda on behalf of
>   his brother Tomii, yakuza, and then escapes with the help of Russel
>   and Seaside Johnny. They run away with data that Inoshiro Tsuburaya
>   needs to achieve the fusion of his mind with artificial intelligence.

So we have a cryo-prison, mercenary, and a red spacesuit, in the right timeframe:

[image: Carmen]

I'm not familiar enough with the series to vouch for the unnatural female anatomy (Google Image results show fairly standard comic book fare), but that is probably the bustiest spacesuit I've ever seen, if that counts.